# Git on https again

Tags: git, github, https

So I've yet to see an answer for this question that is not essentially "use SSH"

SSH is not an option. SSH over HTTPS port is not an option. Both of those time out.

With a repo on GitHub:

```
git pull git@github.com:BenReilly/all-the-characters.git
```

Pushing with SSH just times out, so the git config is set to `insteadOf` SSH calls to the HTTPS equivalent. After adding and committing some files I `git push`

```
Username for 'https://github.com': BenReilly
Password for 'https://BenReilly@github.com':
```

(all normal). Then

```
remote: Anonymous access to BenReilly/all-the-characters.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git/'
```

I am 100% certain I am typing the password correctly. Git is configured to use the proxy.

What can I do to make this work?

edit: cleanup.

git remote -v:

```
origin  https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git (push)
```

Comment: Are you using [two-factor authentication](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-two-factor-authentication)?

Comment: I am not. Will that help?

Comment: No, it would prevent your password from working for CLI authentication. It might have explained your problem. Can you tell us more about your proxy?

Comment: can you show the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: @OznOg added to question